# Add sublist element values if sublist doesn't already exist and else overwrite it

Tags: r, list, nested-lists, sublist

If I have a nested list

```
m=list(list(a=1,b=2,c=3),list(a=1,b=2,c=3))
```

and I have values for an element `d` in a vector, how can I then add these values to nested list `m` if sublist `d` doesn't already exist, and else overwrite values of sublist `d`?

```
lapply(1:length(m),function(i) c(m[[i]],d=d[[i]]))
```

adds the values of vector `d=c(1,3)`, but the problem is that if I do this twice, it will keep on adding sublists `d`, which I don't want - I would rather like them to be overwritten. (I would like to add/replace the 1st vector element to the 1st sublist, the 2nd to the 2nd sublist etc)

How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `modifyList` function might be useful in this case. Just run

```
lapply(m, modifyList, list(d=1:3))
```

And that will replace the values of the sublists in M with the values in the list you specify.

If you had a vector of `d` values and only wanted to add one to each list, then

```
Map(modifyList, m, lapply(c(1,3), function(x) list(d=x)))
```

may be a better option.

Comment: Many thx - but this adds the whole vector then to each sublist element d, whereas I would like to add the first vector element of d to the first sublist, the 2 nd to the second, etc How do I do this?

Comment: Ha found it - that would be lapply(1:length(m), function(i) modifyList(m[[i]],list(d=d[[i]]))) then I think. Thx a lot for the help - hadn't seen this function!

Comment: @TomWenseleers I added a modified answer with less indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
lapply(m,function(x) { x$d <- c(1,3); x })
```

should work (or `x[["d"]] <- ...`)

Comment: Many thx - but this adds the whole vector then to each sublist element d, whereas I would like to add the first vector element of d to the first sublist, the 2 nd to the second, etc